# Are PHP files usable by others when I put my website online?

Tags: php, html, css, web

I created a website using html and css files which I know are supported by web browsers. I also created a php page which is linked to index.html. If I put these files online and make it publicly accessible will my php file work for other users the way it works for me on my localhost? Also, I am using MAMP PRO's free demo so will I need to buy an apache server to ensure that the php file still works for others?

Comment: If you need to run php files in a web page, you need a web server and apache is one of the web servers available. Nginx is another example.

Comment: You should contact the software vendor if you have such questions with the package. Btw., the apache webserver is available for free, you can find the homepage in the internet (in fact large part of that internet is run by it).

Answer (score 1):

I think with "Buying Apache" you mean to buy a webhosting. If not, you do not ned to pay for Apache, its free. With regards to MAMP pro, please elaborate what you are wishing to do with it.

PHP files reside in the web server and the code is not visible to the end user. The web server, such as apache configured with PHP will parse your PHP scripts and renders HTML to the frontend (to the user's browser).

Good luck with your PHP journey.

I advice to take a few short courses prior of trying to put anything live. Especially because of security.

Regards!